# What are ways that academics make money?

Tags: salary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do academics make money from applying their research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/how-do-academics-make-money-from-applying-their-research)

What are the various revenue sources for academics? Are some ways to earn money more usual than others?

I'm asking this question per this [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/how-do-academics-make-money-from-applying-their-research#comment2845_1763).

Comment: What is the difference from http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/how-do-academics-make-money-from-applying-their-research? Perhaps these questions need to be merged.